# Simplemembership Login and RemeberMe ASP.Net MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, simplemembership

I am using ASP.net MVC4 with SimpleMemberShip.

I simply want to store the username if the remember me checkbox is ticked and reload it from the cookie.

Login works fine, RememberMe is set to true. But Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName] is always null. I am confused on how this is supposed to work.

Login Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Index(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        bool RememberMe = model.RememberMe == "on" ? true : false;
        if (WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password, persistCookie: RememberMe))
        {
            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
        return View(model);
    }
```

Login Page Controller:

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Index(string returnUrl)
    {
        // load user name
        HttpCookie authCookie = Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];


        if (authCookie != null)
        {
            FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);
            ViewBag.Username = Server.HtmlEncode(ticket.Name);
            ViewBag.RememberMeSet = true;
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.RememberMeSet = false;
        }
        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: If you just want the username of the currently logged in user why don't you just use the WebSecurity.CurrentUserName property. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.webdata.websecurity.currentusername(v=vs.111).aspx

Comment: I simply want to load the username stored in the cookie by formsauthentication into the username textbox on the login page.

Comment: If you are trying to use it on the login page then I assume the user is not logged in. If they are not logged in then the cookie will be null. If they are logged in then what you are trying to do will work. But as previously stated, if they are logged in it easier to just call WebSecurity.CurrentUserName to get the username rather then trying to pull it from the cookie.

Comment: I think it is about browser, When you first run the browser, it asks to you 'Save Password??'

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to get the username saved by clicking the "Remember me" checkbox. I now understand the cookie is null unless logged in so it was of no use on a login page. For reference I have added my solution below.

Handle Login Request Controller:

```
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Index(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
        {
            // handle remembering username on login page
            bool RememberMe = model.RememberMe == "on" ? true : false;
            HttpCookie existingCookie = Request.Cookies["xxx_username"];

            if (RememberMe)
            {
                // check if cookie exists and if yes update
                if (existingCookie != null)
                {
                    // force to expire it
                    existingCookie.Expires = DateTime.Today.AddMonths(12);
                }
                else
                {
                    // create a cookie
                    HttpCookie newCookie = new HttpCookie("xxx_username", model.UserName);
                    newCookie.Expires = DateTime.Today.AddMonths(12);
                    Response.Cookies.Add(newCookie);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // remove cookie
                if (existingCookie != null)
                {
                    Response.Cookies["xxx_username"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
                }
            }

            if ((!string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.UserName)) && (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.Password)))
            {
                if (WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password, RememberMe))
                {
                    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            TempData["ErrorMsg"] = "Login failed";
            return View(model);
        }
```

Display Login Page Controller:

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Index(string returnUrl)
    {
        // load user name
        HttpCookie existingCookie = Request.Cookies["xxx_username"];
        if (existingCookie != null)
        {
            ViewBag.Username = existingCookie.Value;
            ViewBag.RememberMeSet = true;
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.RememberMeSet = false;
        }
        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        return View();
    }
```